# Previous data being added rather than replaced with current editing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create a simple crud operation using edit and delete. Currently on edit functionality.

Functionality works like this:

1) user clicks on edit icon, bootstrap modal opens up with form information that is fetched from ajax request containing users id. Forms value fields are auto populated based on fetched ajax request.

2) User can edit the auto populating form fields editing the users information and a separate ajax request goes out that edits the users record.

**Problem:**

This all works how I wanted to but I noticed a small bug that I'm stuck on to where when I go edit a users information, hit send and then close out of the modal to open and edit another users information and hit send again, the previous forms data is added onto the data I'm currently editing and I don't want that. I just want to open up the modal and edit and send the current users data that I'm on.

In addition, I also noticed If I keep trying to edit multiple users information, multiple ajax requests are sent each time I try and edit another record. I tried looking up my problem and I think it's because of my events bubbling up in which I tried `e.stopPropagation;` and `return false;` and it did nothing to solve my problem. I feel like I'm close but there is something that I'm missing.

If you need my HTML code as well I'll be happy to show that.

Here is my code:

```js
     $(document).on('click', 'i.fas.fa-edit', function(userId){

      emailField.value = 'Please wait...!';
      fullnameField.value = 'Please wait...!';
      areaField.value = 'Please wait...!';
      personField.value = 'Please wait...!';
      // By Default
      adminAccess.checked = false;
      personField.style.display = 'block';

      adminAccess.addEventListener('click', function(){
       if(adminAccess.checked == true) {
        areaField.style.display = "none";
       } else {
        personField.style.display = "block";
       }
      });

      var usersId = {
       usersId: userId.target.id
      }
      // Select user data
      $.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'select-user-action.php',
       data: usersId,
       success: function(data){

        var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
        
        parseData.forEach(function(element){

         emailField.value = element.email;
         fullnameField.value = element.name;
         areaField.value = element.areaField;
         personField.value = element.personField;

        });
       }
      });
     });
      
      $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {


      submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
       // prevent form from submitting
       e.preventDefault();
       

    var editData = {
     "email": emailField.value,
     "fullName": fullnameField.value,
     "areaField": areaField.value,
     "personField": personField.value
    };

                // Previous data is being added onto current edited data.. This is what I'm stuck on.
       console.log(editData);


       // $.ajax({
       //  method: 'POST',
       //  url: 'edit-user-action.php',
       //  data: editData,
       //  success: function(data){
       //   console.log(data);
       //  }
       // });
          
          // this didnt work
       return false;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Nevermind. I finally figured out the issue. I was adding a event listener every time I opened the modal. I simply needed to move the event listener outside the function and now it's only firing off once thus the data isn't being added on every time I edit a different record.